# File can't combine strings & ints

Tags: c++, string, integer

I am trying to combine Strings and Int to find a file, but I am trying to see if a save file exists, I don't know why it won't work
here is the code, `file.open("Save" + saveNum + ".dat");`

I expected the code to combine the strings and int, the result was an error.

Comment: C++ doesn't support this, you need to convert your number to a string manually by eg using `std::to_string`

Comment: For C++20 use `auto filename = std::format("Save{}.dat",saveNum); file.open(filename);` pre C++20, use the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). Or you can use [std::ostrstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream) as an intermediate step. `std::ostrstream os; os << "Save" << saveNum << ".dat"; file.open(os.str());`